# If a monic $f\in\overline{K}[x]$ has a power $f^n\in K[x]$, where the characteristic of $K$ doesn't divide $n$, then must $f\in K[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose you have a monic polynomial $f(x) \in \overline{K}[x]$, and some integer $n>1$, where  $\mathrm{char}(K)\nmid n$, and  $\big (f(x)\big )^n\in K[x]$. Does it imply $f(x) \in K[x]$?

The question seems very elementary, and my intuition immediately said: "yes", this is true!
However, after few attempts to provide an elementary proof, I got nothing.  I ended up heading to Galois/Kummer Theory, but nothing came out so far. I'm really wondering if such an elementary question has no straightforward answer( with very easy way to prove it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $R \subseteq S$ be a ring extension and $n \in R^*$. Then if some monic polynomial $f \in S[x]$ satisfies $f^n \in R[x]$, then $f \in R[x]$.

Proof: Write $f = x^d + a_{d-1} x^{d-1} + \dotsc + a_1 x + a_0$ with $a_i \in S$. We show by induction on $1 \leq i \leq d$ that $a_{d-i} \in R$. We begin by observing that $f^n = x^{nd} + na_{d-1} x^{nd-1}+\text{ lower terms}$. Hence $na_{d-1} \in R$, i.e. $a_{d-1} \in R$. Now assume that we already know $a_{d-1},\dotsc,a_{d-i+1} \in R$. The coefficient of $x^{nd-i}$ in $f^n$ is $n a_{d-i} + \text{some polyonomial in } a_{d-1},\dotsc,a_{d-i+1}$: The first summand comes from choosing the monomial $a_{d-i} x^{d-i}$ in one $f$, and $x^d$ in the other $n-1$ copies of $f$. In the other summands we have to choose higher monomials. Since a polynomial in $a_{d-1},\dotsc,a_{d-i+1}$ lies in $R$ by induction hypothesis, we conclude $n a_{d-i} \in R$, i.e. $a_{d-i} \in R$. $\square$

Comment: Probably there is also a more abstract proof using power sums and elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: This is nice. Note that we need $char(R)\nmid n$ to get $a_{d-1} \in R$. I also like the fact that this is a contrast to the general
case: $f_1\cdots f_r \in K[x]$ does not imply $f_i\in K[x]$. Since we could certainly pick the $f_i$'s being Galois conjugates.

Comment: $\mathrm{char}(R) \nmid n$ doesn't suffice, we need $n \in R^*$ as I've written (or the weaker assumption that $n : S/R \to S/R$ is injective). Note that the characteristic of an arbitrary ring doesn't have to be a prime number.

Comment: what is your definition of $f^n$, for $n \in R^*$ (i.e. for $n$ not necessarily in $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$)?